# Isn't a reply to an SE email monitored as a ticket is closed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, email

I contacted SE through the contact page on July 17, 2022 (around 12:44 AM). On July 19, 2022 (at 3:08 AM), I got a reply from the Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange Support Team stating that my ticket was escalated to the Trust & Safety team. On July 27, 2022 (at 12:57 AM), I got a reply from a member of the Trust & Safety Team.

I replied to the email which I received from the member of the Trust & Safety Team on August 2, 2022 (at 1:19 AM). On August 2, 2022 (at 1:20 AM), I got an email from SE (community-support@stackoverflow.com):

> Hi,
>
> The ticket you just responded to, ID ***** is closed and is therefore no longer monitored. If you still need help, please feel free to create a new ticket.
>
> Best,
> Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange Support Team.

[image: Screenshot of reply from SE]

I recall replying to emails from SE, but I never got an email stating that I have to create a new ticket as the ticket has been closed. AFAIK, when one replies to the ticket, the ticket gets reopened if it's closed. Is this a bug or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?

---

**Note: The time mentioned above are in [Indian Standard Time (IST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). If a ticket is marked as resolved, folks have 72 hours to respond to it (which will automatically re-open it), otherwise, it goes into a closed state.

Closed tickets cannot be re-opened unless it's done manually, and are not actively monitored. In those cases, if the issue is still present and not resolved, you can create a new ticket and reference the old ticket ID, we'll be able to look it up and continue from there.

Comment: So if one does not reply in few days, the ticket is automatically closed? Sorry, but I don't think it's a good idea. (The OP's case was never resolved, they just got single reply.)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard The ticket is only set as resolved if it's believed to be resolved; most tickets in that state are never responded to. If we need more information from the user, it gets set as a different status with a longer wait period. In either case, once the ticket is closed, the person does get an automatic notification that it happened and can open a new ticket if needed.

Comment: So in this case, the ticket was closed, and then OP's reply "after a few days" fell outside of the 72 hour period, so the ticket wasn't reopened automatically.

Comment: @CesarM So, should I create a new ticket now or should I wait for a reply from SE (through email)?

Comment: @zcoop98 I added specific time in the post now. Please check it.

Comment: @RandomPerson I'm a little confused at your reply; I don't have any sway here, I'm just reading what happened based on the answer's description of the process flow. Staff seems to have closed your ticket, whether intentionally or not. Your response email didn't arrive within 72 hours of the apparent closure, which means the ticket was no longer monitored and your reply went unseen by staff. That sounds to me like you should open a new ticket if the issue you reached out about originally wasn't resolved.

Comment: @zcoop98 Since you mentioned "after a few days" in quotes in https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1270691, I thought that you were interested to know the specific time I sent and received emails. So, I just thought of letting you know that I edited my post. That's it. Regarding creating a new ticket... I'm confused as V2Blast said in a comment that some CM might reply to my ticket (but the comment is now deleted).

Comment: @RandomPerson Gotcha! I apologize. You adding the specific times did confirm it was over 72 hours later, which was helpful, you're right.

Comment: @RandomPerson please open a new ticket and reference the number for the old one, it'll get moved to the right person.

Comment: @RandomPerson: I was getting two different situations mixed up in my head; I didn't want to leave a misleading comment sticking around to cause further confusion after Cesar posted his answer, so I deleted my inaccurate comment. (I'm not on the CM Support team, so Cesar knows the details better than I do.)